# Piping got.stream to a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, node.js-got

I am refactoring some code that was using `http` module in Node to use `got` instead. I tried the following:

```
function get(url, filePath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    got.stream(url).on
        ("response", response => {
            const newFile = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
            response.pipe(newFile);
            newFile.on("finish", () => {
              newFile.close(resolve());
            });
            newFile.on("error", err => {
              reject(err);
            });    
        }).on
        ("error", err => {
             reject(err);
        });
  });
}
```

The `finish` event never fired. The file (`filePath`) is created with 0 bytes.

The block of code using `newFile` was something that worked when I was using the Node `http` module.

What is the proper way to pipe `got.stream` to a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [`got()` documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got#streams), you want to pipe the stream directly to your file and if you use `pipeline()` to do it, it will collect errors and report completion.

```
const pipeline = promisify(stream.pipeline);
const fsp = require('fs').promises;

function get(url, filePath) { 
    return pipeline(
        got.stream(url),
        fs.createWriteStream(filePath)
    );
}

// usage
get(...).then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

FYI, the point of `got.stream()` is to return a stream that you can directly use as a stream and since you want it to go to a file, you can pipe that stream to that file.  I use `pipeline()` instead of `.pipe()` because pipeline has much more complete error handling that `.pipe()`, though in non-error conditions, `.pipe()` would also work.

---

Here's a version that cleans up the output file if there's an error:

```
function get(url, filePath) { 
    return pipeline(
        got.stream(url),
        fs.createWriteStream(filePath)
    ).catch(err => {
         fsp.unlink(filePath).catch(err => {
             if (err.code !== 'ENOENT') {
             // trying to delete output file upon error
                 console.log('error trying to delete output file', err);
             }
         });
         throw err;
    });
}
```

Comment: Using this method, where do I trap errors, like 404?

Comment: @OldGeezer - The `get()` function here returns a promise that will reject when there are errors.

Comment: Thanks. This works, but is there a way to trap the error before `filePath` is created? Now a file of 0 bytes is created even if the url does not exist. Actually, I have a series of actions to take, like making sure the destination folder exists else create it, after the upstream url is found to be ok. My previous method of using `http` and `pipe` allowed me to do all that on the `response` event.

Comment: @OldGeezer - It's doing two things in parallel.  Your best best would be to just delete the output file upon error which you probably want to have code for anyway because not all errors come at the very beginning of the request.  Errors can come during the pipe operation too.  I added an example of that to my answer.